# Excluding Pods from SwiftLint configuration

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, swiftlint

I'm integrating SwiftLint, via Cocoapods, into an existing project.

My project directory is as such:

```
AppNameRepo
|-- AppName
|   |--.swiftlint.yml
|--AppName.xcworkspace
|--Pods
```

And my .swiftlint.yml, as I've tried to exclude pods:

```
included: # paths to include during linting. `--path` is ignored if present.
- Project
- ProjectTests
- ProjectUITests
excluded: # paths to ignore during linting. Takes precedence over `included`.
- Pods
- ../Pods
- ./Pods
- /Pods
- Project/R.generated.swift
- Project/Pods
```

I don't really understand what it's resolving the 'Project' tag to, so I'm grasping at straws here to get to exclude the Pod directory that's up a level from where the .swiftlint.yml file resides.  I tried moving the .swiftlint.yml up a level, so it sat along side /AppName and /Pods, but then no matter what I changed on the included (which, I didn't think would need to be changed as I assumed it recursively worked in), swiftlint would claim there was no lintable files, so I'm at a loss for next steps.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Swiftlint is resolving paths relative to itself. Move the `.swiftlint.yml` file up a level. `Project` should be changed to reflect your AppName folder rather than the project name. Your swiftlint file will look like this:

```
included:
  - AppName

excluded:
  - Pods
```

Answer (score 7):

Since `0.43.0` versión,  you need to specify a path relative to the current working directory, so you can use `${PWD}`:

```
excluded:
  - ${PWD}/Pods
```

Comment: can you describe more? i added this still my Pods directory linting

Answer (score 0):

Although this wasn't the OP's problem, I came across this page and my problem was that my `swiftlint.yml` wasn't added as `.swiftlint.yml`

Answer (score 0):

My solution was moving ".swiftlint.yml" file to the root of the project with finder. Then I've moved from finder to my Xcode project structure.